# log4j2 и Spring Security / MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, log4j2

Задача: логгировать попытки входа. 
Я использую log4j2 и Spring Security / MVC, до этого использовал фильтры и сервлеты. Раньше я просто в сервлете производил логгирование, как такое реализовать в spring?

P.S. Есть предположение отлавливать в контролере /j_spring_security_check, и там писать в лог, но не до конца понимаю, как это делать.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826

Comment: эту доку я читал, но там про первый log4j, а ещё, как я понял, там пример для отладки, а не для протоколирования событий. Если не прав, поправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Смысл не меняется, только конфирурацию пишите для второй версии, а не для первой. тут http://www.javabeat.net/log4j-2-spring-mvc/ пример конфигураци и как вообще использовать в MVC. Внутренности SpringMVC тоже должны логироваться, не уверен насколько подробно.

Comment: спасибо большое, можете оформить свой комментарий, как ответ и я отмечу его верным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для включения логирования надо добавить файл конфигурации, в вашем случае это log4j2 в classpath. Пример файла и полной настройки логирования можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.javabeat.net/log4j-2-spring-mvc/)